# Mouse over Color in Java

Tags: java, colors, mouse, mouseover

I need to make a game in Java for a project.

What I'm trying to do is a game where you have to go through a maze without touching the walls.

Is there a way to get the color of the pixel the mouse is over?

Comment: Get the co-ordinates the mouse is at, this tells you which pixel it's over and then check the colour of that pixel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want java.awt.Robot.getPixelColor(x, y). It'll be faster than grabbing an image.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=20&threadID=283174) answers your question precisely including a complete working code example. Basically, you can create an image from canvas on which you draw and call getRGB() on a pixel on the image.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement the MouseMotionListener interface and do what Artelius mentioned, namely, get the coordinates of the mouse position and calculate the color of the pixel.